# Create sparse matrix using custom ngram list?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, text-classification, n-gram

I am trying to create a sparse matrix for text classification using bag of words, but the problem is that my code creates the ngrams based on the text itself. I have a custom ngram list for which I want to create the sparse matrix. How do I do this in Python?
Below is the code I have written which creates sparse matrix using ngram on its own:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(
analyzer = 'word',
lowercase = True,
stop_words = 'english',
max_features = 85
)
corpus_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data.Query.tolist())
```

Comment: Take a look at the second half of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618950/using-countvectorizer-to-compute-word-occurrence-for-my-own-vocabulary-in-python/49620845#49620845. I think it applies in your case as well.

Comment: @KRKirov Thank you for the link. It will partially help me but since we are again specifying the ngram_range in the code you mentioned, it will create additional unigrams from the bi-grams in my vocabulary and I do not want that. Can you suggest a workaround for that?

Comment: And If I just use vocabulary parameter set to my_vocabulary (which has some unigrams and bigrams), the transform function is not giving results for bigrams even if it is present in the document

Comment: Please post an example of your ngram list and of the text which you want analyzed for the presence of these ngrams so that I can generate the sparse matrix. A few ngram terms and a few text lines should be sufficient.